# Connection between dual space V* and negation P^c

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, category-theory, tensors, duality-theorems

Notice the following similarity between the vector space dual and negation in propositional logic:

$$ V^* \equiv V \rightarrow F $$
$$ P^c \equiv P \rightarrow \bot $$

Is there some general notion of duality behind this?

Also, a tensor is known to be of type $V \times \cdots \times V \times V^* \times \cdots \times V^* \rightarrow F$
or perhaps more suggestively $V \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow V \rightarrow V^* \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow V^* \rightarrow F$.

Does this give an equivalent notion of a "tensor" in propositional logic? Perhaps through Curry-Howard?

Comment: $\bot$ corresponds more to $0$ than $F$, I think.

Comment: @Zhen: yes, I noticed this after writing my answer, but dualizing objects are as dualizing objects do... for example, for locally compact abelian groups the dualizing object is $S^1$.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I'm thinking more in terms of universal properties than dualisation. Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction you describe can be carried out in any [closed monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category). The ones relevant to propositional logic are the ones where $\otimes$ denotes "and" and $\Rightarrow$ denotes "implies." See also [compact closed category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_closed_category), [Heyting algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra), and [linear logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic).

A good general introduction to these ideas can be found in Baez's [Physics, Topology, Logic, and Computation: A Rosetta Stone](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0340).